# FluentMigrator: How to support fluent migrator for multiple database with same schema

Tags: .net-core, fluent-migrator

We have a multi-tenant architecture design with multiple databases with the same schema and We are using .net core 3.1 for the migration project.

I'd like to run fluent migration on all the databases. what is the right way to set up the migration runner to run the migration on multiple databases with different connection strings in dot net core?

Answer (score 1):

Just found the question.
Nothing magic in FluentMegirator. You have to loop through the databases, and for each database configure the runner supplying the connection with "WithGlobalConnectionString", and then migrate.up, inside the loop